# Smoothly enlarge a small image

Tags: windows, gratis, image-processing

I am looking for a gratis Widows app, which can take a small, blocky, image - like this:

[image]

and enlarge it, smoothing it out, so that it it is not blocky & pixelated, making it at least presentable at A4 size -curvy, with no jaggededges..

Please, zoom in on the image, to see how bad it looks if not transformed.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option may be to recreate the image using a vector program such as [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (free, multi-platform). Inkscape supports bitmap tracing, which will reduce the workload a bit.

I've taken your tiny bitmap and ran it through the tracing and the results were not particular encouraging. It does a form of color separation, but that would require manual adjustment to get the level of detail inherent in the image.

Once converted to vector, enlarging the image causes no deterioration.

You may get suggestions that the Graphic Design SE would have been a better location for your question, but the answers are likely to be similar.